# React Spring REST sessions don't persist

Tags: spring-boot, session, spring-rest

I have a react tic tac toe component in which I'm accessing the following rest controller mapping:

Spring REST side:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(value = "http://localhost:3000", allowCredentials = "true")
public class TTTController {

    @GetMapping("ttt")
    public TTTMove makeMove(@RequestParam int x, @RequestParam int y, HttpSession session) {
        if (session.isNew()) {
            session.setMaxInactiveInterval(maxTimeOut);
            session.setAttribute("map", new TTTMap());
        }

        var map = (TTTMap) session.getAttribute("map");
        ...
    }
}
```

React side:

```
const request = axios.create({
    withCredentials: true,
    baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL
})

...

await request.get("ttt", {
   params: {
       x: _x,
       y: _y
   }
```

The problem is that those sessions are dropped randomly (after 1-2 requests).

Same behavior via fetch instead axios.
Same behavior with regular Controller instead REST

Comment: try changing: @CrossOrigin(value = "http://localhost:3000", allowCredentials = "true") to @CrossOrigin(value = "http://localhost:3000",allowedHeaders = "*", allowCredentials = "true"). If this does not work , try double checking that axios is sending the cookie values.

Comment: @codemonkey inspecting network activities i've found that the
first request sends cookie x0, receives x1;
next sends x1, recieves no cookie
and on the third request it sends cookie x1 (looks good) but receives cookie x2 (thats where new session is started), so the error isn't in the frontend i suppose